# Unable to run simple Java app with JRE 10

Tags: java, java-10

Just tried to run my application in JRE 10 (since 9 got killed recently). The error below indicates that it requires ant.jar but this is a complete nonsense. The application **doesn't need** ant to run, and it works perfectly fine with all JRE's all the way back to 7. What am I missing? Why the runtime demands something which is totally irrelevant?

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/Execute
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.EnvironmentConfiguration.extractProperties14(EnvironmentConfiguration.java:160)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.EnvironmentConfiguration.<init>(EnvironmentConfiguration.java:77)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.interpol.EnvironmentLookup.<init>(EnvironmentLookup.java:51)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.interpol.ConfigurationInterpolator.<clinit>(ConfigurationInterpolator.java:386)
.......
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
```

Comment: Have you recompiled it with Java 10 before trying to run it? Also, does this happen with all your programs? What's the first line of yours in the stack trace?

Comment: One possible start is to check each of the libraries that are you using to make sure that you have a version that supports JDK 10.

Comment: @ tobias_k, no I don't compile with Java 10. The app is build with Java 7 and doesn't require anything more than that, it's a relatively old application, as far as I know it's been running on any possible JRE out there starting from 6. The only reason I had to try 10 is because JRE9 vanished from downloads. Whatever replaced it seems to be a weird replacement.

Comment: @Alan Bateman, I have few dozens of (well known) open source libraries as dependencies. Isn't the advancement to Java 10 supposed to be backward compatible? Or will it break the entire stack of things on the way..?

Comment: Here's the JDK 10 migration guide: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/migrate/toc.htm . If you do only one thing then check each of libraries that are using to see if they are certified to work on JDK 9 and 10.

Comment: @Alan Bateman, thank you for the reference. I wasn't looking at migration at this moment. I was just making sure that the existing app will just work for those who happened to have installed Java 10. It appears that the answer is categorically not, it breaks things and demands rigorous migration and release of updates before anyone can start using Java 10. Fair enough. I have actually found the problem, will post an answer shortly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you have a dependency to a rather old version of apache commons-configuration. I could neither find the mentioned line in version 1.10 nor in 2.2.

If you would elaborate the sources of the apprioriate version, I guess you will see something like `super(new HashMap<String, Object>(System.getenv()));` and in `extractProperties14(..)` (which I was not able to find in the above mentioned versions) some code that accesses `org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute` due to some logic.

So, I suggest to update the version of the dependeny or, if you are not allowed to do so, remove the SystemProperty that causes the error and seems to be provided by the JRE by default.

Comment: yes, thank you, just found it, see the answer posted below

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found the answer but it may be opening more questions at this point. Well, at least the application seem to function as before. The offending dependency is  **commons-configuration-1.7.jar**. Once upgraded to **commons-configuration-1.10.jar**, everything is good again. Or it seems. Frankly, I don't know how to contain the march of upgrades in java world lately...